# Attention Text Generation in Character-by-Character fashion

Tags: neural-network, nlp, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I am searching the web for a couple of days for any **text generation** model that would use only attention mechanisms.

The **Transformer** architecture that made waves in the context of **Seq-to-Seq** models is actually based solely on **Attention** mechanisms but is mainly designed and used for translation or chat bot tasks so it doesn't fit to the purpose, but the principle does.

My question is:

Does anyone knows or heard of a text generation model **based solely on Attention without any recurrence**?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I'm familiar with **PyTorch**.

Comment: You mean no RNN inside (no LSTM and GRU)?

Comment: Yes, sir. No recurrence, or even if there is, the attention should be the central part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a character-level self-attentive model is a challenging task. Character-level models are usually based on RNNs. Whereas in a word/subword model, it is clear from the beginning what are the units carrying meaning (and therefore the units the attention mechanism can attend to), a character-level model needs to learn word meaning in the following layers. This makes it quite difficult for the model to learn.

Text generation models are nothing more than conditional languages model. Google AI recently published a paper on [Transformer character language model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10322), but it is the only work I know of.

Anyway, you should consider either using subwords units (as BPE, SentencePiece) or if you really need to go for character level, use RNNs instead.

Comment: Excellent paper!

Comment: Thank you very much sir! As far as I know Transformers are Seq-to-Seq models, so they are not generative models. Even GPT-2 needs a subject phrase to be feed to the Encoder before generating the story in the Decoder.